# My eclipse won't work with my java

Tags: java, eclipse

Hi i'm a 13 year old programmer and I am having a problem running my eclipse. I just did a reinstall for my java version. Now when i try to run eclipse it gives me these error messages:

Error: opening registry key 'Software\Java Soft\Java Runtime Enviroment'
Error:could not find java.dll
Error:Could not find Java SE Runtime Enviroment

Some help would really be appreciated with my problem.

Comment: This kind of question - about software installation and associated problems will usually get better answers at superuser.com

Comment: Also see [this thread](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/203884/) on the Eclipse forum.